# Write headers when splitting large csv files using java

Tags: java, csv, file, split

I want to split a 1 million row CSV file into smaller chunk files with 10000 each. I need to store header once and then write into all the split files. Basically for example if number of lines to be split are 3 then writing to split files should happen with 3 lines + header.

```
public static void splitCSV(final String fileName, 
                        final String extension, 
                        final int maxLines) {

try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(String.format("%s.%s", fileName, extension)))) {
    int file = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(String.format("%s_%d.%s", fileName, file, extension)));

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        writer.write(s.next() + System.lineSeparator());
        if (++cnt == maxLines && s.hasNext()) {
            writer.close();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(String.format("%s_%d.%s", fileName, ++file, extension)));
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    writer.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```